# Cannot access any controllers but the default controller in Code Ignite

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-2

In Code Igniter, I am trying to access a method from the controller, but it gives me a 404 not found error. Maybe it is a problem with the .htaccess file or config?

My base url is set as:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeIgniter/';
```

I tried to access:

```
http://localhost/codeIgniter/pages/index
```

but it returned a 404 not found error.

Comment: Do you have a `pages` controller? Have you set CI up to use clean URLs?  You haven't given us enough information to be able to help, much.

Comment: I have a the pages controller in my project. I dunno where set CI to clean URLs, what more information you need? i may edit the post

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file? Hello this apache? Mod_rewrite?

Comment: Have you read the CI documentation on using clean URLs?  It's there.

Comment: just posted now my .htacess file, and Mod_rewrite is on

Comment: are you sure the file name of `.htaccess` is right on your localhost?? if then are you sure your localhost Apache server is running?? I have just tried your code in my localhost is't working fine.

Comment: Actually, your base_url is looking pretty suspect...Whats the project dir structure?

Comment: there is the root(codeIgnite), i just added more directories in views i created: content and template, template is like the core of the site, header, menu and footer, and in content i have the content of pages.

Comment: where is you index.php located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing index.php from url just after your project name

try using this url:

```
http://localhost/codeIgniter/index.php/pages/index
```

Comment: got it, works now, i have changed routes.php file configuration

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
RewriteBase /codeIgniter
```

to .htaccess

Comment: What about `http://localhost/codeIgniter/index.php/pages/index`? This one should work even when `.htaccess` is missing.

Comment: when i access http://localhost/codeIgniter/ works. works when i put index.php before the class but a bit bugged

Comment: it loads page/index normal when i access http://localhost/codeIgniter/, if i try access a class in url it gives me a 404 error

Comment: Ok, you don't need the `RewriteBase` rule in `.htaccess`. It doesn't harm but it doesn't help either.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: just can acess now, the problem was in routing file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be some problem by the version of codeigniter you use if you are using codeignter latest version use

```
class class_name extends CI_Controller
```

other wise

```
class class_name extends Controller
```